# python open() how to change set files name/title

Tags: python

If I open a file (image) in python with

`f = open('/path/to/file.jpg', 'r+')`

I have a function `f.title()` and I get the full path of the file back.  How can I change the opened files name/repr/title to something else?

Answer (score 2):

You don't change filenames using `open`, that's for sure. You'll want to use [`os.rename`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename).

But if you're trying to change the name the file has within your program but NOT the actual filename, why are you trying to do that/what would be the point in that? I guess you could detach the buffer from the file object and assign it to a new object with the title you want, if you're working with Python 3 (thought you could do it in Python 2(.6) as well, but don't see any mention of the `detach` method in the documentation of the Python 2.6 `file` object or its `io` module), but really, I don't quite see the point...

Oh wait, if you just want the filename for use elsewhere and don't necessarily need to change the name itself:

```
import os.path

f = open('/path/to/file.jpg', 'r+')

print(os.path.basename(f.name))  #don't include the parentheses if you're working in Python 2.6 and not using the right __future__ imports or working in something prior to 2.6
```

This will output 'file.jpg'. Not sure if it helps you if `blob.filename` is an automatic assignment, though, unless you're willing to subclass whatever class `blob` is...

Comment: i open the file and i push it up to my appengine. i want to change the  files name to have only the filename stored as the blob.filename instead of the full path i uploaded it from.

Comment: @aschmid00: Yeah, I realized that that was probably what you wanted. See my updated answer.

Comment: ok but how do i set this name to the opened files metadata before i multipart_encode the file to send it up to the site?

Comment: @aschmid00: You probably should edit the original question, or ask another question, rather than look for solutions in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me (Python 2.6, on Windows); I have to use the "name" attribute:

```
>>> f = open(r'C:\test.txt', 'r+')
>>> f.title()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'title'
>>> f.name
'C:\\test.txt'
```

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects), "name" is read-only.  And unfortunately, you can't set arbitrary attributes on file objects:

```
>>> f.title = f.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'title'
```